# Contar peticiones de Google Maps

Tags: php, google-maps, symfony, symfony4

Estimado estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en symfony 4, estaba utilizando google maps pero ahora que ya no es mas gratuita, la consulta es si google te brinda alguna result donde se pueda ver la cantidad de peticiones que lleva contada la api?

Comment: Lo puedes revisan en la consola
https://console.cloud.google.com/
Tambien hay presupuestos y alertas para que te notifiquen que estas apunto de excederte.

Comment: En la consola puedes ver la quota e incluso las peticiones.